# In Xcode, some variables showing as [0] when inspecting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to assign a UIImage to a UIImage property and in the bottom left of Xcode (in the variable inspector) there is a variable [0] that doesn't list a variable's name, and when I breakpoint and inspect the UIImage property is also shows [0] in the popup?

It appears that I'm unable to assign to the property as well.

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Never trust the debugger variable display.  To inspect a pointer variable type `po myPointerName` in the "console" window.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have an Array or Dictionary, Xcode enumerates the objects as [0][1][2]...[n]. If the object is from a known type, it will let you inspect it. Otherwise, it won't.

Also, if the object has already been allocated in memory, right near the [n] you will have its physical address. If it hasn't, that space will be left blank.